# 403 Forbidden You don't have permission to access / on this server. on Mac OS

Tags: apache2.4

I am trying to define a new virtual host on my local host and try to access it via https . when i try to access https://localhost.mydomain.com i get the error

403 Forbidden You don't have permission to access / on this server.

my httpd.conf entry is below

```
ServerRoot "/usr"

Listen 80

LoadModule authn_file_module libexec/apache2/mod_authn_file.so
LoadModule authn_core_module libexec/apache2/mod_authn_core.so
LoadModule authz_host_module libexec/apache2/mod_authz_host.so
LoadModule authz_groupfile_module libexec/apache2/mod_authz_groupfile.so
LoadModule authz_user_module libexec/apache2/mod_authz_user.so
LoadModule authz_core_module libexec/apache2/mod_authz_core.so
LoadModule access_compat_module libexec/apache2/mod_access_compat.so
LoadModule auth_basic_module libexec/apache2/mod_auth_basic.so
LoadModule socache_shmcb_module libexec/apache2/mod_socache_shmcb.so
LoadModule reqtimeout_module libexec/apache2/mod_reqtimeout.so
LoadModule filter_module libexec/apache2/mod_filter.so
LoadModule mime_module libexec/apache2/mod_mime.so
LoadModule log_config_module libexec/apache2/mod_log_config.so
LoadModule env_module libexec/apache2/mod_env.so
LoadModule headers_module libexec/apache2/mod_headers.so
LoadModule setenvif_module libexec/apache2/mod_setenvif.so
LoadModule version_module libexec/apache2/mod_version.so
LoadModule proxy_module libexec/apache2/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_connect_module libexec/apache2/mod_proxy_connect.so
LoadModule proxy_ftp_module libexec/apache2/mod_proxy_ftp.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module libexec/apache2/mod_proxy_http.so
LoadModule proxy_fcgi_module libexec/apache2/mod_proxy_fcgi.so
LoadModule proxy_scgi_module libexec/apache2/mod_proxy_scgi.so
LoadModule proxy_wstunnel_module libexec/apache2/mod_proxy_wstunnel.so
LoadModule proxy_ajp_module libexec/apache2/mod_proxy_ajp.so
LoadModule proxy_balancer_module libexec/apache2/mod_proxy_balancer.so
LoadModule proxy_express_module libexec/apache2/mod_proxy_express.so
LoadModule slotmem_shm_module libexec/apache2/mod_slotmem_shm.so
LoadModule ssl_module libexec/apache2/mod_ssl.so
LoadModule lbmethod_byrequests_module libexec/apache2/mod_lbmethod_byrequests.so
LoadModule lbmethod_bytraffic_module libexec/apache2/mod_lbmethod_bytraffic.so
LoadModule lbmethod_bybusyness_module libexec/apache2/mod_lbmethod_bybusyness.so
LoadModule unixd_module libexec/apache2/mod_unixd.so
LoadModule status_module libexec/apache2/mod_status.so
LoadModule autoindex_module libexec/apache2/mod_autoindex.so
LoadModule negotiation_module libexec/apache2/mod_negotiation.so
LoadModule dir_module libexec/apache2/mod_dir.so
LoadModule alias_module libexec/apache2/mod_alias.so
LoadModule hfs_apple_module libexec/apache2/mod_hfs_apple.so

<IfModule unixd_module>
User _www
Group _www    
</IfModule>

ServerAdmin you@example.com

Servername localhost.mydomain.com

DocumentRoot "/Users/<usernamehidden>/dev/myaccount"
<Directory "/Users/<usernamehidden>/dev/myaccount">
Require all granted              
Options FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
AllowOverride All
</Directory>

<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.html
</IfModule>

<FilesMatch "^\.([Hh][Tt]|[Dd][Ss]_[Ss])">
    Require all denied
</FilesMatch>

<Files "rsrc">
    Require all denied
</Files>
<DirectoryMatch ".*\.\.namedfork">
    Require all denied
</DirectoryMatch>

ErrorLog "/private/var/log/apache2/error_log"
LogLevel warn

<IfModule log_config_module>
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common

    <IfModule logio_module>
      # You need to enable mod_logio.c to use %I and %O
      LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %I %O" combinedio
    </IfModule>

    CustomLog "/private/var/log/apache2/access_log" common

</IfModule>

<IfModule alias_module>

    ScriptAliasMatch ^/cgi-bin/((?!(?i:webobjects)).*$) "/Library/WebServer/CGI-Executables/$1"

</IfModule>

<IfModule cgid_module>
</IfModule>

<Directory "/Library/WebServer/CGI-Executables">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<IfModule mime_module>
    TypesConfig /private/etc/apache2/mime.types

    AddType application/x-compress .Z
    AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz

</IfModule>

TraceEnable off

Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-mpm.conf

Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-autoindex.conf


<IfModule proxy_html_module>
Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/proxy-html.conf
</IfModule>

Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-ssl.conf
<IfModule ssl_module>
SSLRandomSeed startup builtin
SSLRandomSeed connect builtin
</IfModule>
Include /private/etc/apache2/other/*.conf
```

`

when i try to access https://localhost.mydomain.com i get

403 Forbidden You don't have permission to access / on this server

I have tried all the combinations recommended on stack overflow

I have followed below to generate self styled certificate and install SSL on local host

```
http://brianflove.com/2014/12/02/enable-https-in-apache-on-mac-yosemite/
http://brianflove.com/2014/12/01/self-signed-ssl-certificate-on-mac-yosemite/
```

I am using Apache2.4 on Mac OS

Why am i getting You don't have permission to access / on this server.

```
http://localhost.mydomain.com works perfectly


https://localhost.mydomain.com is the issue
```

Answer (score 0):

There was nothing wrong with my config, My application lacked a index file. tomcat was trying to serve index.html  / .php / .jsp and could not find it, finally it tried to serve content from root for which it had no access. so the root cause is not having a proper index file